# how to find the best postions in a matrix?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, matrix

I need to build a seating system for a Java course I am attending.

Given the amount of seats required, the system needs to give the best positions in the hall.

By best positions I mean that the seats have to be as close as possible to one another, and as close as possible to the mid row.

Now, some definitions:

Distance between seats - The minimal number of cells in the matrix that separates the two cells. For example, the distance between the cell [3,3] and [2,2] is 1.

I thought about doing a recursive backtracking function that will give me a list of all possible positions, which I'll then iterate through, grading it by the distance between all the positions and the distance of all the seats from the mid row.

This solution would be extremely inefficient. Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: i would love to answer that but i haven't learn the graph theory yet so i can't understand the algorithm

Comment: that might work but then again i haven't learn the graph theory yet( i am taking the relevant course but we have a long way to that),i guess i can try to read the link you gave me but i hardly think my lecturer would expect us for this much effort there must be an easier solution can you think of another way maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how Dijkstra applies here, unless i misunderstand the problem.
Is your preference is first to adjacent seating, and then to distance to middle row?
i.e. Say you need to find 5 seats, and you have five consecutive seats available in first row, and then 4 available seats in middle row, then I am assuming the solution would be to choose 5 seats in first row.

So, given a required seat number N...
What I would do, is to start with middle row, pick an empty seat, and "grow" a region by flagging all adjacent empty seats. If the region is size N, then you are done. If its not, then I would push this region on a stack (say location of the "start of growth" and number of empty seats in that cluster). Then I would move on along the middle row marking/growing such regions. After middle row I would move one up and then one below. Then two up and two below, etc, until entire matrix is covered. The trick is, keep finding empty clusters until you hit one that is of size N. If you process the entire matrix and no such cluster exists, you can comeback to the stack and "smartly" pick empty clusters that add up to at least N.

Hope that helps. Fun problem.

Comment: i think i got it,you mean to grow to adjacent empty seats but what if there aren't any adjacent empty seats? and after i covered all the matrix how i find the best cluster

Comment: I guess what i meant was, say you need to find 6 seats. So first see if you can get a cluster of 6 seats in the middle row. If not, look for a cluster of 6 seats in (middle row - 1) and (middle row + 1), if not, etc. Interim, push each find cluster (with number of seats) onto your stack. If you process whole matrix and no cluster of 6 seats found, then your best choice will be a cluster of 5 seats + 1 closest seat. That can be found by looking at your stack, starting in front, until you find a cluster of 5 and pick one seat from first cluster of stack. If not look for 4-cluster, etc.

Comment: Coincidentally, Algorithm would probably be a better tag for this question.

Comment: In your example i found a cluster of five why shouldn't i find the closest seat by going over the matrix but by the first available seat in the first cluster in the stack, and algorithm tag would be better